# How to tell node.js to treat .js files in dependency as esm modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I'm currently rewriting some internal packages as ECMAScript modules. Unfortunately, I depend on some external packages that use *esm* syntax but *.js* file endings. Of course, they have neither `"exports"` nor `"type": "module"` defined in their *package.json*. I cannot update these external dependencies to new versions.

How can I tell node.js to treat these *.js* files as *esm* modules?

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the file name is, as long as they are received with the correct MIME type. [Node.js' documentation on how to specify `import` is relatively clear](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-specifiers); they give examples with both .mjs and .js and includes the note *"Including the file extension is only necessary for packages without an "exports" field."*

Comment: MIME type is irrelevant for node.js. And as I explicitly state in my question, I'm talking about dependencies that **do not** specify an _exports_ field in their package.json.

Comment: The rules are pretty simple.  Nodejs will assume the file you're asking it to load is an ESM module ONLY if it has an `.mjs` file extension or if it's package.json has a `"type": "module"`.  If neither of those is true, then it loads the module as CommonJS.  If you're using 3rd party modules that are ESM, then they should have `"type": "module"` in their package.json.  If they don't and aren't `.mjs`, it's unclear how they could ever work as ESM modules and you should file bugs on them and/or fork them to fix

Comment: Yeah, sure. Newer versions of the dependencies would work, but since they are several major versions ahead, that would be huge rewrites for me. Since _.js_ has been the JavaScript file ending since the beginning of times and _.mjs_ is very new, a way to tell node.js to treat _.js_ files as esm in dependencies would be very appreciated.

Comment: Modules are responsible for their OWN package.json which tells how they should be loaded.  This is the module's requirement.  You don't have callers specify what type of module it is in nodejs.  That's just not how it works (for very good design reasons).  It's not going to do you one bit of good to keep asking for something that doesn't exist or grumbling about why it isn't that way.  Anyone who coded an ESM module and didn't properly specify that it's an ESM module in the package.json file - that's just a BUG.  It's wrong.  The module must be fixed.  Nobody can properly use it.

Comment: ES6 module syntax was specified and used long before node.js decided upon forcing a specific file extension or package.json configuration. It works perfectly fine in browsers. That's not a bug. I don't have a problem with any of node.js' design decisions. It's all fine. I'm just asking for a way to override a specific behavior that makes it very hard to maintain legacy code.